# Get both row headers and column headers in telerik's radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, telerik

I'm facing a problem with the use of the telerik's radgrid. So far i have been using simple grids with only column headers.
I need know to get row headers.

I'm trying to work with this which is more or less what i am looking for :
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/pivot/defaultcs.aspx

the problem the Row/Column headers are not the column names from my table. I need to write them directly in the code.
Some help would be welcome!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know if this is exactly what you like, but ...

Could declare the column in the grid (aspx):

```
<MasterTableView>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="RowHeader"></telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

And in the event ItemCreated assign the value:

```
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
{
    ((GridDataItem)e.Item)["RowHeader"].Text = "nononono";
```

Comment: Thank but this is not extactly what i'm looking for ... i get this :
http://hpics.li/a4b7782

all are in the same row...
The text must be in the beginning of every row....